# Can I enforce that fields in a POCO are only ever set in a type initialiser?

Tags: c#, poco, code-analysis, cql, ndepend

If I have a POCO such as this:

```
[Poco]
public class MyPoco
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

... and it's initialised like this:

```
new MyPoco { FirstName = "Joe", LastName="Bloggs", Address="123 Abc St." }
```

Can I, using CQL in NDepend, ensure that the properties are only ever set using the object initialiser as above, and not separately.

I'm trying to catch code like this:

```
myPoco.FirstName="John";
doSomething(myPoco);
```

... I don't want people to set properties on an **existing POCO**.  I understand I can make the setters `private`, but I don't like passing in all the properties in a constructor because you end up with a signature such as `MyPoco(string, string, string)` - making it easier to misalign the parameters (easier than using the object initialiser syntax)

So, I want to catch this using NDepend.  Here's the start of my CQL query:

```
from f in JustMyCode.Fields.Where(f=>
   f.ParentType.HasAttribute ("JetBrains.Annotations.PocoAttribute".AllowNoMatch())) 
       where f.MethodsAssigningMe [I'M STUMPED HERE]
```

It looks like I can analyse the **method** setting the property of a POCO, but I need to go one step lower and examing the code block to see if it's in an object initialiser block.

Is this possible?

Comment: In C# next this will be a "thing" (primary constructors). In C# current, you'd need to write explicit properties to do this.

Comment: What about named parameters. You can set the setters to private and use var *myPoco = new MyPoco(firstName: "", lastName: "", address: "");*

Comment: @MarcGravell: The primary constructors won't help in terms of the calling code though, will it? You won't be able to use object initializer syntax to create an instance, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed, it'll be constructor similar to Jernej's comment above - but the point I was not making very well is that it is a simple way of creating a proper immutable type without all the cruft that you need today

Comment: @MarcGravell: Agreed, and I'm very happy about that - but I don't think it's particularly relevant to the question in this case. (The OP's stated objection to putting things in the constructor isn't the ugliness of having to write manual properties and separate readonly variables.)

Comment: @Jon yeah, but IMO the "making it easier to misalign the parameters" is based on a false premise, avoidable by naming the parameters in the call

Comment: With NDepend you can write a rule to ensure that if a method uses a setter of a POCO class, it uses all setters of the POCO class. But you cannot enforce that all these setters are called in an object initialiser.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether you can do this in CQL, although even if you can't, you might well be able to do it with Roslyn.

However, you might want to consider using a builder pattern instead:

```
var poco = new MyPoco.Builder { FirstName = "Joe",
                                LastName="Bloggs",
                                Address="123 Abc St." }.Build();
```

Now the poco itself can be immutable, but the builder can have the properties set wherever you like.

Heck, if you're a fan of implicit conversions you *could* even have an implicit conversion from the builder to the poco:

```
MyPoco poco = new MyPoco.Builder { FirstName = "Joe",
                                   LastName="Bloggs",
                                   Address="123 Abc St." };
```

While I'm all for tools verifying proper coding where it's not possible to design a type to avoid it being misused to start with, I'd prefer to have an idiot-proof API to start with :)

Also note that with named arguments in C# 4, even the constructor version can be made clear:

```
var poco = new MyPoco(firstName: "Joe",
                      lastName: "Bloggs",
                      address: "123 Abc St.");
```

but of course that still *allows* people to write it without the named arguments...